# Retrive object id contained in pointer from parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I'm building an application with parse. When logging in it pulls user data from the User class. Involved in this are two pointer fields that point to other entries in different classes.

I would like to extract the objectId's saved in these pointer fields and save them locally. I'm currently having issues with just extracting the objectId however.

Currently I use the line of code:

```
NSSString *clubObjectIdFind = [user objectForKey:(@"club")];
```

Where club is the pointer column concerned

However this returns: 'Club: 0x7fa6149288a0, objectId: H0XLN2krKS, localId: (null)'

As opposed to just: 'H0XLN2krKS' which is what I would like.

It's likely a very simple question, but is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Instead of string, do this (pseudo code): NSDictionary *clubObjectIdFind = [user objectForKey:(@"club")]; Then drill into the dictionary to find the objectId key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns you object from Pointer already.

Use `objectId` to reference or fetch this object later:

```
PFObject* object = (PFObject*)[user objectForKey:@"club"];
NSString* objectId = object.objectId;
```

Comment: This method worked perfectly. Thanks for your help. The solution seems fairly obvious to me now but I couldn't see it at all before. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
NSSString *clubObjectIdFind = [[user objectForKey:(@"club")]objectForKey:@"objectId"];
```